# Converting inches to feet

Tags: c

This was a homework assignment that I'm now done with - I submitted it as is. However the fact that I needed to use the same code twice bugged me... The double code is:

```
printf("Enter a distance in inches (0 to quit): ");
scanf("%f",&input);
```

Is there a better way to do the same thing in my loop instead of the double `scanf`/`printf`? It does need to quit the program immediately if a 0 is entered.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float distance, floatFeet, input;
    int feet;

    printf("Enter a distance in inches (0 to quit): ");
    scanf("%f", &input);
    while (input != 0)
    {
        feet = input/12;
        distance = (input-feet*12);
        floatFeet = input/12;
        printf("%d feet and %f inches or %f feet \n\n", feet, distance, floatFeet);
        printf("Enter a distance in inches (0 to quit): ");
        scanf("%f", &input);
    }
}
```

Comment: there is a codereview.SO where questions like are better suited

Comment: And off we go...

Comment: I would flush the output before reading for the input..

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In general, you would need to insert an explicit conditional somewhere in order to distinguish between the first iteration (when no results should be displayed before the prompt) and any subsequent ones. That's because the "do not display output" condition is different from the "exit program" condition, so you can't just shove both into the loop condition.

Since you are going to insert an `if` no matter what, you might as well make it break out of the loop and make the loop infinite:

```
while (1)
{
    printf("Enter a distance in inches (0 to quit): ");
    scanf("%f",&input);

    if (input == 0) break;

    feet = input/12;
    inches = (input-feet*12);
    floatFeet = input/12;       
    printf("%d feet and %f inches or %f feet \n\n",feet,inches,floatFeet);
}
```

Comment: In C, you'd probably want while(1), not while(true).

Comment: @Antimony: So true, thanks (no pun intended). I 've blown my cover! ;-)

Comment: while (true) throws an 'undeclared' error at me, should I just use while (1)?

Comment: ah okay thanks antimony, comments didn't refresh right away :P

Comment: In C, the idiom for "infinite loop" is `for(;;) { .... }`

Answer (score 30):

You could move the duplicated lines into a function, something like this should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

float get_input(void)
{
    float input;

    printf("Enter a distance in inches (0 to quit): ");
    scanf("%f", &input);

    return input;
}

int main()
{
    float inches, floatFeet, input;
    int feet;

    while (input = get_input())
    {
        feet = input/12;
        inches = (input-feet*12);
        floatFeet = input/12;
        printf("%d feet and %f inches or %f feet \n\n",feet,inches,floatFeet);
    }

    printf("Goodbye!\n");
}
```

Comment: @mskfisher, thanks! Maybe out of scope though, if the OP has not learned about functions and such yet.

Comment: +1, because it's more elegant than all the other solutions. However, I would extract the first 3 lines from the while block also into a method (calculate_output or something like that). Also, the answer lacks the check for 0.

Comment: I would too, but restricted my answer to just what the OP was asking about. The 0 is checked by `while`.

Comment: @Marton `while(input = get_input())` checks whether `input` is 0.

Comment: @DanielFischer Oops, sorry, I just never use `while(0)`

Comment: @Marton It's not `while(0)`, it's `while(input)` - except that `input` also gets assigned when the loop condition is evaluated.

Comment: +1, however I would move variable declaration to the first place they are used.

Comment: @marco-fiset This is possible in C99 but not in classic C. C99 doesn't really seem to have set off yet

Comment: @FelixDombek: True, I have not programmed in C for a really long time! Did not remember that one.

Comment: Sorry but this is not elegant! `while (input = get_input())` will cause confusion for any beginning C programmer. Marton's comment shows that even experienced ones will fall for that trap!

Comment: Yes it can confuse the beginning C programmer, but nevertheless it's an elegant solution, using the given assumption (using the 0 as stop sign)

Comment: @Alexander Thanks, programming has been my job for several years now, but I never used (and will never use) while like this. Exactly because it's confusing. But I learned something new today :)

Comment: Better would be `while ((input = get_input()) != 0)` which won't give a compiler warning and doesn't confuse the assignment with a boolean.

Answer (score 10):

You can use a `do while` loop, which will always execute once and check the condition at the end of the loop.

If you need the program to exit immediately without printing when a 0 is entered, you could just put the calculation and printing code in an if statement within the loop:

```
do {
    printf("Enter a distance in inches (0 to quit): ");
    scanf("%f",&input);
    if( input != 0 ) {
        feet = input/12;
        inches = (input-feet*12);
        floatFeet = input/12;       
        printf("%d feet and %f inches or %f feet \n\n",feet,inches,floatFeet);
    }    
} while (input != 0)
```

Or, to avoid repeating anything:

```
while(true) {
    printf("Enter a distance in inches (0 to quit): ");
    scanf("%f",&input);
    if( input == 0 ) {
         break;
    }
    feet = input/12;
    inches = (input-feet*12);
    floatFeet = input/12;       
    printf("%d feet and %f inches or %f feet \n\n",feet,inches,floatFeet);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can replace this loop with a "forever" loop that exits from the middle of its body, like this:

```
for (;;) {
    printf("Enter a distance in inches (0 to quit): ");
    scanf("%f",&input);
    if (input == 0) break;
    feet = input/12;
    inches = (input-feet*12);
    floatFeet = input/12;       
    printf("%d feet and %f inches or %f feet \n\n",feet,inches,floatFeet);
}
```

There are multiple ways to do a "forever" loop; this one is borrowed from K&R's book.

Comment: Any reason to use a for loop instead of a while loop when making a 'forever' loop?

Comment: @Symon I use `for(;;)` because it is a very common idiom popularized by ["the" book](http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Language-2nd-Brian-Kernighan/dp/0131103628) on the C language. Other than that, there is no reason to go one way or the other: the compiler will generate identical binary code for both loops.

Comment: Some people even define: `#define ever (;;)`

Comment: @mouviciel: People who have just not learned to *leave the preprocessor alone if at all possible*.

Comment: @Symon In a compiler which does not optimize at all, `while (1)` might generate a comparison to a constant which is omitted in `for (;;)`. However, all normal compilers would optimize that comparison away.

Answer (score 5):

Use `do-while` instead `while`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float inches, floatFeet, input;
    int feet;

    do
    {
        printf("Enter a distance in inches (0 to quit): ");
        scanf("%f",&input);
        if (input == 0) break;
        feet = input/12;
        inches = (input-feet*12);
        floatFeet = input/12;       
        printf("%d feet and %f inches or %f feet \n\n",feet,inches,floatFeet);      
    }
    while (input != 0);
}
```

Comment: "It does need to quit the program immediately if a 0 is entered." This would print "0 feet and 0 inches or 0 feet".

Comment: That depends on what you mean by immediately. Since the code executed before quitting has no side effects, it shouldn't matter.

Comment: @Antimony The side effect is printing a line. I don't think that "shouldn't matter"...the code as edited will work though (although there is an extra comparison every time the loop loops).

Comment: @Lc Oh I didn't notice that. Ok I see the problem now.

Comment: Also, if you're breaking out explicitly, there's no point in a do loop. Just make it while(1).

Comment: @Antimony The two methods may be functionally equivalent; but the do-while construct makes it explicit that it's not intended to be an infinite loop.  That said, I'd probably replace the `if (input == 0) break;` construct with `if(input !=0) { ...}`and put the rest of the loop inside the {}'s to eliminate the second exit point from the loop as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly where you use the:

```
do {
    //stuff
} while (condition)
```

... where you need to do something once, at least, but conditionally repeat the same task...

Answer (score 0):

Symon, here is another alternative.  Notice the following things:

1. I have separated getting input into a function, `get_input`.  The function takes a pointer to a variable to accept the input value and checks whether `scanf` actually reads a value from the user input.  It returns an integer value that is non-zero (true) if `scanf` really did read a value.  The exit condition has changed to `ctrl-d` which is the standard UNIX way of indicating end-of-input. Equally, typing a non-numeric will also cause `scanf` to return 0.
2. The `while` loop now exits on failure of the input function.
3. The variables are defined at the point of use. This is better practice as it reduces the scope  of the variable (ie. the amount of the code where it is valid).
4. `distance` is renamed `inches`, which seems more appropriate.
5. The division is done only once and there is a cast (int) to avoid a conversion compiler warning (turn many warnings ON in your compiler).
6. A new-line is printed on exit to be nice to the user.

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>

   static inline int get_input(float *input)
   {
       printf("\nEnter a distance in inches (ctrl-d to quit): ");
       return scanf("%f", input) == 1;
   }

   int main(void)
   {
       float input;

       while (get_input(&input) != 0) {

           float float_feet = input / 12;
           int feet = (int) float_feet;
           float inches = input - (feet * 12);

           printf("%d feet, %f inches or %f feet \n", feet, inches, float_feet);
       }
       putchar('\n');
       return 0;
   }
   ```